# Unable to access EC2 Instance via public IP after reboot

Tags: amazon-web-services, amazon-ec2

Unable to reach EC2 Ubuntu 18.04 server via Public IP

1. Rebooted working EC2 instance
2. Restarted normally, no errors
3. Security Groups, check inbound OK on 80,443 & 22
4. Able to ssh to server
5. Can ping server from another EC2
6. instance on same VPC/subnet
7. Curl to private IP works from another
8. EC2 instance on the same VPC/subnet
9. Netcat shows server listening on port 80
10. Other instances in VPC are fine, they are using the same security group

What else can I check?

Comment: i doubt this will be it but to answer 'what else can i check' - there's network ACLs that can block access

Comment: PublicIP changes when you stop and start your instance, do you know this?

Comment: Yes, I am trying new IP assigned on reboot. Also tried associating an Elastic IP (which changes IP again) but no luck, thx

Comment: @jimsproultexas check my answer's edit. See if it works.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

I don't have enough reputation to add a comment, but another thing to check would be whether your web server (apache/nginx) is actually running. If not, then try

```
sudo systemctl start apache2
```

OR

```
sudo systemctl start nginx
```

Note: If you're not using a static IP on your EC2, your instance has changed IP address. You probably already know this since you can still ssh into your instance.
But a consequence of this is that you will need to update your apache conf file to point to your new public IP.

Check all .conf files under `/etc/apache2/sites-available` and see if they contain the right IP address in `ServerName` field. Then reload apache.

```
sudo systemctl reload apache2
```

OR disable then enable conf files

```
sudo a2dissite your_conf_filename
sudo a2ensite your_conf_filename
```

Comment: Thanks, apache is ok. It is listening on port 80 which is why I tested with curl. Thanks

Comment: Can you check if your active virtualhost conf file has the public ip in ServerName?

Comment: YES - The problem turned out to be the vhost configurations relying on DNS names that had not been updated.   Thanlks All

Comment: Glad to hear that. Could you please mark my answer as 'accepted'? :)

Comment: @jimsproultexas Um?

Comment: I appear to be unable to "accept" answer from Mythos but it did lead to the solution

Comment: @jimsproultexas That's weird. Did you click the grey tickmark below the downvote button?